# How do I programmatically attach debugger in JetBrains plugin?

Tags: plugins, jetbrains-ide

I want to attach the debugger to a some process via action
In my `actionPerformed` code I have this

```
XDebuggerManager.getInstance(project).startSessionAndShowTab(...)
```

The problem is that `startSessionAndShowTab` has 4 overloads and I don't know where can I take these parameters

```
XDebugSession startSessionAndShowTab(
    @NotNull @Nls String sessionName,
    Nullable RunContentDescriptor contentToReuse,
    NotNull XDebugProcessStarter starter)

XDebugSession startSessionAndShowTab(
    @NotNull @Nls String sessionName,
    NotNull XDebugProcessStarter starter,
    NotNull ExecutionEnvironment environment)

XDebugSession startSessionAndShowTab(
    @NotNull @Nls String sessionName,
    @Nullable RunContentDescriptor contentToReuse,
    boolean showToolWindowOnSuspendOnly,
    @NotNull XDebugProcessStarter starter)

XDebugSession startSessionAndShowTab(
    @NotNull @Nls String sessionName,
    @Nullable Icon icon,
    Nullable RunContentDescriptor contentToReuse,
    boolean showToolWindowOnSuspendOnly,
    @NotNull XDebugProcessStarter starter)
```

These calls are undocumented and I have not found any useful information
`SessionName` is ok, it sounds like a name for a debug tab in tool menu
`RunContentDescriptor` - no clue, probably some kind of information about currently selected run configuration. Didn't figure out how can I access an instance of it
`XDebugProcessStarter` - Didn't figure out where can I get/create an instance of it
`ExecutionEnvironment` -

I understand that there can be plenty debuggers available for a single process, I need to hardcode "Native" one for Rider
May be there's an easier way exist with call like `DebuggerManager.attach(pid, "Native")` or how can I make above work in `AnAction` context? I want the same behavior as `Run -> Attach to process... -> [select process] -> Click Attach with LLDB` but programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The second overload of `startSessionAndShowTab` seems appropriate:

```java
XDebugSession startSessionAndShowTab(
    @NotNull @Nls String sessionName,
    @Nullable RunContentDescriptor contentToReuse,
    @NotNull XDebugProcessStarter starter)
```

It is the simplest one that allows for starting a debugging session, with the parameters:

1. **`sessionName`**: A `String` that names your debug session: it is just a string to identify your debug session.
2. **`contentToReuse`**: A `RunContentDescriptor` that can be `null` if you do not need to reuse existing content.
3. **`starter`**: An instance of `XDebugProcessStarter`, where you implement the logic to create and return your specific debugger process. That is where most of the work will be.

For more complex scenarios, like attaching to specific processes or using advanced features, one of the other overloads might be more appropriate. But not in your case.

To attach to a specific process, like a native one for [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), you would likely need to interact with lower-level APIs specific to Rider and possibly [LLDB](https://lldb.llvm.org/). That is more complex and not typically exposed through the high-level [`XDebuggerManager` API](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/23bb68de04cfd849d615dac6ceaa2738e5bd431d/platform/xdebugger-api/src/com/intellij/xdebugger/XDebuggerManager.java).

A simplified example to attach a debugger would be:

```java
import com.intellij.debugger.DebuggerManager;
import com.intellij.debugger.engine.JavaDebugProcess;
import com.intellij.execution.executors.DefaultDebugExecutor;
import com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment;
import com.intellij.execution.ui.RunContentDescriptor;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.xdebugger.XDebugProcessStarter;
import com.intellij.xdebugger.XDebuggerManager;
import com.intellij.xdebugger.XDebugSession;

// In your actionPerformed method
Project project = ...; // Get your current project
DebuggerManager debuggerManager = DebuggerManager.getInstance(project);

XDebugProcessStarter starter = new XDebugProcessStarter() {
    @Override
    public XDebugProcess start(@NotNull XDebugSession session) throws ExecutionException {
        // Here you need to create and return an instance of your debugger process.
        // For a Java process, it might look something like this:
        return JavaDebugProcess.create(session, new RunContentDescriptor(...));
        // For native processes, you will need a different implementation.
    }
};

XDebugSession session = XDebuggerManager.getInstance(project).startSessionAndShowTab(
    "My Debug Session", // session name
    null, // runContentDescriptor, null if you do not need to reuse
    starter // your custom debug process starter
);
```

For native debugging in Rider with LLDB, you will have to dive into Rider's specific APIs and possibly directly interact with LLDB, which could be significantly more complex and might not be fully supported through the public API.
Warning: a [debug session in Rider will be much slower than other  IDE](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/14jc0r0/jetbrains_rider_debug_is_about_10x_slower_than/).

I do not see a simple `DebuggerManager.attach(pid, "Native")` method in the JetBrains API.